# To find a Linux software library version from shell terminal

Tags: shared-libraries, version

How do we check and find out any Linux software library version currently being installed (and correctly running), by command on bash terminal

Answer (score 1):

> How do we check and find out any Linux software library version currently being installed (and correctly running), by command on bash terminal

Depends on what you mean by "and correctly running", and which package manger your system is using.

On Debian and variants, `dpkg -l ${packagename}`. On RedHat, `yum info ${packagename}`. etc. etc.